# expressjs, use regular exp to match route

Tags: node.js, express

I use a regular exp to match a path and route the request to `pageRouter`.
When I request the localhost:8000/new, the regular EXP looks not work, but I have test the EXP use `/^\/(?!api$|api\/.*|resource$|resource\/.*)/.test('/new')`, it return true.
What happened?

```
router.use('/api',apiRouter);
router.use('/resource',resourceRouter);
router.use(/^\/(?!api$|api\/.*|resource$|resource\/.*)/,pageRouter);

pageRouter.get("*",(req,resp,next)=>{let name = req.originalUrl...})
```

Comment: It seems you are trying to exclude `/api`  and `/resource` by the regular expression. You don't need to. As  `/api`  and `/resource` router are defined before pageRouter, they will be triggered first, not the one defined inside pageRouter. Just use `router.use('/', pageRouter);`, so that all URL except `/api`  and `/resource` will be listened by pageRouter.

Comment: That will cause that: the /resource.. will first through resourceRouter then through pageRouter.But I just want the /resource through  resourceRouter .

Comment: Really? Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from the expressjs's github,the link is https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/3404

> It is not just a matter of does the regular expression match the
>   input, but since .use needs to strip down the matched path, it expects
>   your match to stop before a / character to cut on.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, instead of `regexp` you just need to use the `wildcard` :

```
const express = require('express'); const app = express()

app.get('/api', function(req, res){ res.send('API·Router') })
app.get('/resource', function(req, res){ res.send('RESOURCE·Router') })
app.get('/*', function(req, res){ res.send('[*] PAGE.Router') })

app.listen(3000)
```

**Its important to define all the other routes before the wildcard** '`/*`'

**WHY?** : If your first route is the wildcard, it will trap all the requests

---

## Detecting Paths using Wildcard

```
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
 var paths = req.path.split("/")
 if(paths[1].length==0){
  res.send('[/] Page.Root')
 }else if(paths[1]=='portal'){
  if(paths[2]){ res.send('[*] PAGE.Router : '+paths[2]) }
  else{ res.send('[*] PAGE.Router : '+paths[1]) }
 }else{ res.send('[404] PATH : '+paths[1]+' not found!') }
});
```

---

## Using an array :

If you have a **specific** list of routes that you want to use for pageRouter you can always group them inside an array for the first argument of the `app.get`() handler :

```
const pageRoutes = ['en/page','es/pagina','dk/side','jp/頁']
app.get(pageRoutes, function(req, res){ res.send('[*] PAGE.Router') })
```

Comment: I have test the
router.use('/api',apiRouter);
router.use('/resource',resourceRouter);
router.use('/:page',pageRouter);
That not works since the /api.. will be first through apiRoute then through /pageRoute

Comment: @sinbar /:page is not what I told you to do in this answer. If you use the wildcard, then check/split the req path instead to see what it was requested in the wildcard path /*.

Answer (score 0):

It seems OP is trying to exclude `/api` and `/resource` for `pageRouter` by regular expression. However, it's not needed. As long as `/api` and `/resource` router are defined before `pageRouter`, they will be triggered first, and won't go though `pageRouter` any more.

**Just define `/api` and `/resource` before `pageRouter`, and then use `router.use('/', pageRouter);`, so that all URL except `/api` and `/resource` will be listened by `pageRouter`.**

Here is the example code. I've verified and confirmed that HTTP request to `/resource` won't go through `pageRouter`.

Files:

```
./app.js
./routes.js
./pageRouter.js
./resourceRouter.js
```

For `./app.js`:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const routes = require('./routes');

app.use('/', routes);

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
});
```

For `./routes.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

const resourceRouter = require('./resourceRouter');
const pageRouter = require('./pageRouter');

router.use('/resource',resourceRouter);
router.use('/', pageRouter);

module.exports = router;
```

For `./resourceRouter.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with resource');
});

module.exports = router;
```

For `./pageRouter.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/resource', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('hit /resource in pageRouter');
  res.send('respond with page by /resource');
});

router.get('/new-page', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with page by /new-page');
});

router.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('hit * in pageRouter');
  res.send('respond with page by *');
});

module.exports = router;
```

After running `./app.js`, the HTTP `GET` request for `/resource` would never hit `./pageRouter.js`.

Comment: what's your express version? 
I test you code with no any change,the browser show:"respond with resource" and the console log "hit * in pageRouter" ,it indicate that request through both resourceRouter and pageRouter

Comment: My Express version is 4.13.4, and I'm running the app inside WebStorm (should be the same as running from cli)